# How to Change Application's Default Execution Priority

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, priority

Is there a way to change an application's default execution priority in Windows XP?  I've heard that an application's installer usually sets its priority, so I'm thinking that there must be a registry setting somewhere that can do this.

Comment: Any luck since then?

Comment: Perhaps there can be a resident application or a service that watches the list of processes running, waits for a particular executable to emerge in it and changes its priority then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have *never* seen an application run on any priority other than "Normal" unless I changed it.  You can always change applications priorities in the Task Manager or launch it with a different priority from the command line.

Comment: How do I launch the application from the command line with a different priority?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191771  You can change an apps shortcut to use this command so when launching it via the shrotcut, the priority will be set.